# Simple Pong game will not run as an .exe

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I am new to this forum and have limited python experience. Since this quarantine I decided to get back into learning python. I have over the past few days made some working games using both curses and pygame. These games function properly on my PC however I would like to get them into an .exe format. I have used pyinstaller in order to create the .exe however my pong game (which uses pygame) crashes once you try to open the .exe file. I am assuming it may have something to do with the import of pygame. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to my code on GitHub:
https://github.com/nick-cheshire/PythonGames-/blob/master/Pong.py

Thanks to @TheBigKahuna I was able to create a .bat file and run it and here are the errors I recieved :

```
``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pong.py", line 137, in <module>
    pong()
  File "Pong.py", line 90, in pong
    game_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
  File "site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1472, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
[18912] Failed to execute script Pong``
```

Comment: If you make a .bat file and use the command `call file.exe` and `pause` you should be able to see the error message. To make sure its pygame

Comment: @TheBigKahuna How would I go about doing that and or what would I put in the .bat file?

Comment: This is me assuming your on windows, as .bat is a windows thing. Create a new .txt file, type in it `call ` then the name of the exe. then in the next line type `pause` then save as whatever with `.bat` at the end, run it, and it will run your program and print the error. [link to creating a batch file](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001666.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work. The problem was with font. Change your line

```
game_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
```

with

```
game_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)
```

I assume that the problem is with locating the file. Please correct if I am wrong. 
Now when making .exe with pyinstaller, make sure your file is named `main.py` and since you are building a GUI you will want -w (without a console) parameter. So, I suggest running powershell as administrator, navigate to your main.py and:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @nches157 You are welcome! Glad I could help! Consider marking as an answer if it resolved all the issues. Thanks